# Axes separated in a plot

Tags: r, plot

So I've got a plot with customized axes. **I want the axes to be joined**, but they get separated when I customize them with the `axis()` function.

Here's the code that generates the plot:

```
plot(smodelesp0,col=2,lwd=2,xlab="Tiempo en Días",ylab="Proporción de Frees",
main="Proporción de Usuarios Free pasados X días según Perfil",axes=F)
axis(1,at=seq(0,250,by=10),labels=seq(0,250,by=10),lwd=2)
axis(2,at=seq(0,1,by=0.1),labels=seq(0,1,by=0.1),lwd=2)
lines(smodelesp1,col=4,lwd=2)
legend("topright",c("Perfil de máximo riesgo","Perfil de mínimo riesgo"),col=c(2,4),lwd=2)
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Any idea? Am I skipping some parameter in the axes function?

Comment: You didn't supply any data so the plot and problem aren't [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You'll probably also want to specify `xlim=` and `ylim=` in the plot since `axis()` only controls where labels are printed, not the range of values plotted.

Comment: Suspect you are just wanting to do `box(bty="l")` after drawing the axes, in this case with `lwd=2` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example from the help file of `axis` with a tweak

```
plot(1:4, rnorm(4), axes = FALSE)
axis(1, 1:4, LETTERS[1:4], lwd=2)
axis(2, lwd=2)
```

[image: plot 1, mind the gap]

Now join them with box

```
box(bty="l",lwd=2)
```

[image: now with "L" shaped box]

Comment: We've got a winner! Thank you pal!